# app creashed on login with new user account

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dropbox

my iphone app creashes  when login with new dbuser on dropbox within my iphone app. this is the error

```
 [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error loading DBConnectController - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x2226f540 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=db-ku1fs4zz0jho1c1://1/connect?oauth_token=nqtkpp9hegrqlok7&oauth_token_secret=cmkjfe2jyyxebi9&uid=223802279&state=97E25614-8D69-499D-B72C-DEC8128916C7, NSErrorFailingURLKey=db-ku1fs4zz0jho1c1://1/connect?oauth_token=nqtkpp9hegrqlok7&oauth_token_secret=cmkjfe2jyyxebi9&uid=223802279&state=97E25614-8D69-499D-B72C-DEC8128916C7, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x22126880 "unsupported URL"}
```

Comment: Need more explanation.

Comment: the issue is when i login with a user first the very first time then. it successfully displayed all dropbox files and folder in tableview. but after logout first user. then i login with another user then app creashes with the above log message

Comment: Judging, by [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749687/i-got-an-error-when-connect-to-www-google-com-use-nsconnection) you or the Dropbox SDK is trying to fetch a domain without a URL scheme (i.e. http://, https://)

Comment: I am also experiencing this error. I can successfully log in with one account, but once I unlink from Dropbox and attempt to log in with another account, this error occurs. Maybe it's a bug in the Dropbox iOS SDK.

Comment: I added some detail to this and posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126030/dropbox-ios-sdk-webkit-discarded-an-uncaught-exception

Comment: Same problem on OSX with sandbox - enable incoming and outgoing network connections